# how can I filter a list of sentence to only keep phrases contained in a list of phrases

Tags: python, list

Here are some initial lists:

```
list_of_phrases = ['community is', 'or language', 'opinion-based']


list_of_sentence = ['The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems. Avoid asking opinion-based questions.']
```

expected new list:

```
list_of_sentence = ['community is or language opinion-based']
```

if there is no match, I want list_of_sentence to show:

```
list_of_sentence = ['None']
```

Comment: If a string is in the list twice should it be returned twice or just once?

Comment: should return twice. order of the words in the list of sentence should be maintained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_str = list_of_sentence[0]
new_list = []

counter = 0

for phrase in list_of_phrases:
    if phrase in new_str:
        new_list.append(phrase)
        counter += 1

if counter == 0:
    list_of_sentence = ['None']
else:
    list_of_sentence = [' '.join(new_list)]
```

Comment: How does this keep the order of the full string or deal with duplicates?

Comment: It doesn't. Duplicates can be dealt with by using a set.

Comment: Could you modify the code to ensure absolute phrases are selected? for example the code is picking up the word leed in the word bleeding. leed should only be a match if its a word or phrase on it's own

Answer (score 0):

Use the *in* operator.

if string1 in string2:

You can use for loops to move through the lists

Answer (score 0):

using

```
import re
my_str = 'The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems. Avoid asking opinion-based questions.'
community_list = [occ.start() for occ in re.finditer('community is', my_str)]
```

would give you all the occurences of `community is`. Do the same for the other words and then create a new string using the locations in those lists and you got your string.

Comment: Need an approach that makes use of pattern and/or regex with findall

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should do the job

```
list_of_phrases = ['community is', 'or language', 'opinion-based']
list_of_sentence = ['The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems. Avoid asking opinion-based questions.']
for phrase in list_of_phrases.copy():
    if phrase not in list_of_sentence[0]:
        list_of_phrases.remove(phrase)

list_of_sentence = [' '.join(list_of_phrases)]
if len(list_of_sentence) <= 1:
    list_of_sentence = ['None']
```

you can put it in a function too but it's up to you.

Comment: list_of_sentence not returning None when no match

Comment: @BerceyEfund Now it should work, I modified the condition